# Groovy code to insert String Array into Oracle table

Tags: arrays, grails, groovy, oracle11g

I have a groovy program with code as below:

```
String[] conceptArray = conceptList.toArray()
```

I am trying to insert conceptArray into Oracle table like below

sql.execute("insert into OFFICE.PERSON(CONCEPT) values (?)",[conceptArray]);

But the above code is not inserting values into the table Person. Please help me to correct the above code.

Comment: Are you trying so insert a single row, or a row per entry in `conceptArray`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the groovy.sql.Sql class:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html

```
def sql=new groovy.sql.Sql(...)
String insert="insert into OFFICE.PERSON values (${conceptList.collect{'?'}.join(','})"
sql.executeUpdate(insert,conceptList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL prepared statement (which is created with the GString and ? syntax) is expecting a string to insert where the `?` is, but you are passing it a `List`. You will need to turn the list of values into a `String`, which you could do this way:

```
String conceptsString = conceptList.join(',')
sql.execute("insert into OFFICE.PERSON(CONCEPT) values (?)", [conceptsString])
```